# Change image position in runtime

Tags: android, image

I want to change position of image(imageview) in runtime. I put imageView in FrameLayout. My main layout is relative layout.

I tried many things but always got null pointer exception.

Last time i tried this:

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams par;
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.im1);
    par = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)image.getLayoutParams();
    par.setMargins(100,100,0,0);

    image.setLayoutParams(par);
```

xml for imageView:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/im1"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:src="@drawable/im1"/>
```

I figured something. SetX and SetY change position but they work only in OnCreate method of main class. I want send this imageview object to another class and use it in functions. When i use it, it doesn't give any error but doesn't change positions.

Comment: Which line causes nullpointer?

Comment: I don't know. I tried comment each line but always gives an error.

Comment: Look at your Logcat. It will say on which line you get NullPointerException.

Comment: I guess it gives every line with "image". I initialize it like "image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1)" in onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize image using findViewById instead... (If you haven't..)
Or just use setY() and setX().

Comment: I initialize it in onCreate method. I tried to use just setX it also doesn't work.

Comment: Oh. So have you made sure your view isn't anchored in the xml layout? For examle a view that is set to center horizontally and vertically cant be moved.

Comment: I added xml for imageView. Is there any problem?

Comment: Can you add the xml declaratio?

Answer (score 0):

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.markerImage)
```

You have no id called `im1` in your `xml` hence raising the `NullPointerException`

Comment: I change id later, for understand error. I can't change my old code here so i change my new update code while copying here. Sorry i forget change it.